# Get culture info of the system using win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am working win32 console application. I want to get the current system locale or culture info in my win32 application.
**Like en-US or zh-CN.**

Is there anything provided by WINAPI.

Sample code for this will really help.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [GetLocaleInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoa).

```
wchar_t szISOLang[5] = { 0 };
wchar_t szISOCountry[5] = { 0 };

::GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
    LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME,
    szISOLang,
    sizeof(szISOLang) / sizeof(wchar_t));

::GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
    LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME,
    szISOCountry,
    sizeof(szISOCountry) / sizeof(WCHAR));

std::wcout << szISOLang << "_" << szISOCountry << std::endl;
```

[image]

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon. Links break over time. Answers should be self contained, relevant info and examples should be in the answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

In C or C++, you can create a locale based on a name, so if you supply a name like `en-US` it will create a matching locale (assuming you use one of the strings it knows about--obviously most libraries aren't going to recognize every possible string).

This has one little-known feature though: if you supply an empty string, it will create a locale that's appropriate for the environment as configured by the user (determined by some means the language doesn't specify).

So, you can retrieve that, and use it. For example:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    auto loc = std::locale("");


    std::cout << loc.name() << "\n";
}
```

On the machine I'm using at the moment (Linux), this prints out: `en_US.UTF-8`.